# iOS Container View and Parent ViewController communication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, communication

How can I communicate with container view controller and parent view controller? I've tried to make a communication and pass the value between them. I've added a container view in the green view controller. And I had set segue name with "communicateSegue".  I've searched some methods, I know we can set the prepareForSegue to pass the value at initial.

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"communicateSegue"]) {
         NSLog(@"call prepare for segue at parent view controller");
     }
 }
```

But now I want to pass value and change the label in the different viewcontroller . Not at the initial.

I don't know how to do?

**Question:**

Have anyone know how to implement ParentViewController pass value to Container View Controller and show the label in the ContainerViewController?

And reverse , Container View Controller click the button then pass the value and change the label show in the ParentViewController with objective-c?

Thanks.

My declare variable in parentViewController.h:
     #import

```
 @interface ParentViewController : UIViewController
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *parentTF;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *passValToChildVCBtn;

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *showContainerValLB;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet IBAction *passValueToContainerEvent;

 @end
```

In the ContainerChildViewController.h
     #import

```
 @interface ContainerChildViewController : UIViewController
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *showParentValLB;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *childTF;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *passToParentBtn;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet IBAction *passValueToParentBtnEvent;

 @end
```

[image]

[test project in the here](https://github.com/dickfalaDeveloper/ContainerCommunicateDemo.git).

thank you very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding passing value to the containerView controller, you can make a property in the ChildViewController of the value you want it to be passed. Then in your ParentViewController do something like the following:

`self.ChildViewController.yourProperty = yourValue`

The opposite can be done in 4 ways:

- You can make a delegate protocol to communicate the data between your controllers.
- You can post a notification in your ChildViewController and add the parent controller as an observer.
- You can use KVO.
- And the easiest way out, you can make a property in your parentviewController and access it like the following

  ```
  ((YourParentViewControllerClassType *)self.parentViewController).yourParentProperty = TheValueYouWant;
  ```

Comment: thanks, Can I ask you detail? If I click button in the ParentViewController, But How can I get child label value, I had try to  self.showContainerValLB.text = self.childViewControllers.childTF.text;
    . That can't find self.childViewControllers.childTF.text . And Can You explain detail or offer simple code about the child view controller pass value to parent viewcontroller in button action using delegate? I just practice delegate , but encounter some problem, I post this sample project just I want to try and practice project.thank you again.

Comment: self.childViewControllers will get you an array. You can loop over them till you find the child class type or you can keep a reference of the child itself. About the delegate, make a protocol in your child view and conform on it in your parent view. Then in the delegate method send whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this:

1. set identifier for segue from your containerView to viewController
2. make property/variable myChildViewController in your parent view controller and property/variable myParentViewController in your child view controller
3. in your prepareForSegue method set this properties to be the reference to right objects
4. Now you can access to properties of parent/child view controller through this references.

Example in Swift:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifier" {

        // Set references
        myChildViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! YourChildViewController
        myChildViewController.myParentViewController = self
    }
}
```

Example in Objective C

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourIdentifier"]) {

         // Set references
         myChildViewController = [segue destinationViewController]; 
         myChildViewController.myParentViewController = self
     }
 }
```

I did't try the objective C code becouse I don't ever use it. It is just an example to get the idea.

After that you can set any property of parent from child view controller as:

```
myParentViewController.property = value
```

and in your parent view controller:

```
myChildViewController.property = value
```

Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 1):

Is pretty simple, the `UIStoryboardSegue` contains a reference to your destination view controller using the property `-destinationViewController`.
In the method `-prepareForSegue` you can access it and pass the data that you need.
If you need to pass data from child to parent, I strongly suggest you to avoid hard coupling and use something such as delegation or notification pattern.
Remember that your parent view controller already contains a reference to you child view controllers and you can simply access it by using `-childViewControllers` property.

Comment: thanks, But prepareForSegue is pass value in the initial. I want to learn how to pass value and show the value on the screen in the button action.I prefer to use delegate, but I don't know how to implement in the case. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use NSNotificationCenter for updating all screens or you can do this way..

create a property in `ContainerChildViewController.h`

```
 @property(nonatomic,copy)NSString * mytextString;
```

this property will be accessible in your `ParentViewController.h` if you import `ContainerChildViewController.h`

you have to create a NSString in `ParentViewController.h`

in this you can set button action to copy `textfielddata.text`
then you can assign this value to your `ContainerChildViewcontroller's`
as

// create an instance of 2nd view controller as second in `ParenViewController`

```
UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   ContainerChildViewController * second= [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContainerChildViewController"];
        second.mytextString = self.mytextString;
// either you directly pass this value or use the string it should work both ways
        NSLog(@"%@",second.orderID);
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
```

Reply if it works

Comment: I had try to add identifier. Then I add ContainerChildViewController *ccVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContainerChildViewController"]; in the parent viewcontroller. In the button action,I will get null about NSLog(@"get container textfield:%@",ccVC.childTF.text); @@

Comment: where you logging is happening in first view controller,
you have to copy textfield.text to "mystring.text"
then you are passing that mystring.text  to second.yourstring

Comment: In The ParentViewController,at the viewDidLoad.- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
        myStorybaord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ccVC=[myStorybaord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContainerChildViewController"];
}Then I put the ccVC.childTF.text = @"test put from parent"; in the button action at ParentViewController. that was not effect.@@

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (IBAction)showDetail:(UIButton *)sender {

        DetailViewController *detailVc = [self.childViewControllers firstObject];
        detailVc.lable.text = sender.titleLabel.text;

}
```